# Is there eslint-react rule that forces to use functional setState only?

Tags: eslint

I actively use `eslint-plugin-react` and recently read about [functional setState](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b). I wanted to use eslint rule for this, but couldn't find. Is there eslint-react rule that forces to use functional setState only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

Currently, there is no such `eslint-plugin-react` rule available.

## Additional information

### Related issues

There are the related GitHub issues:

1. [Rule idea: Disallow accessing this.state within setState · Issue #943 · yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/943).
2. [Rule Suggestion : setState function · Issue #1196 · yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1196).
3. [Rule proposal: Require/Disallow passing an object to `setState()` if not using previous state · Issue #1836 · yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1836).

Please, take a look at them.

### «Closest» issue

The issue #2 from the «Related issues» list — [Rule Suggestion : setState function · Issue #1196 · yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/1196) — seems to be **the closest to or the same as** your question (request).

The implementation-related issue: [Rule idea: Disallow accessing this.state within setState · Issue #943 · yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/943).

It seems the feature was implemented somewhat partially.
Partially, because:

1. It disallows only the use of `this.state` within the `setState()` argument: both object initialiser and function.
2. While it **still allows** passing an object (without using `this.state` in its object initialiser) as the `setState()` function argument. For example:

   ```
   this.setState({quantity: 2});
   ```

Please, consider reporting the details to the existing «closest» issue to make an attempt to re-open it or open a new issue.